# Jquery change enter key press to tab key

Tags: jquery

I made a page for data entry. This page has several input boxes. Presently, when the user press return key after entering data in the input box, the form gets submitted. I want to enable form submission on pressing return key only if the focus is on submit button. Other wise it should move to next input. I tried several method, nothing worked. Please suggest a way

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('Connections/hari.php');
$dateindian = date('d-m-Y');
$dateus = date('Y-m-d');
if (isset($_SESSION['EMPNO'])) {
    $ECNO = $_SESSION['EMPNO'];

    mysql_select_db($database_hari, $hari);
    $auth_sql2 = "SELECT pdw FROM users WHERE emp_no='$ECNO'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($auth_sql2)or die(mysql_error());
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result2);


    $_SESSION['pdw_priv'] = $row2['pdw'];
    mysql_free_result($result2);


    if ($count == 0 or $_SESSION['pdw_priv'] == 'N') {


        header('Location:unauthorised.php');
        exit();
    }
} else {
    header('Location:esl_login.php');
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <!-- DW6 -->
    <head>
        <!-- Copyright 2005 Macromedia, Inc. All rights reserved. -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>System Efficiency for Alpha/Beta Counters : : ESL, KAIGA</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home_style_login.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/water_quality.css" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/DatePicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                submitHandler: function () {
                    var usin = jQuery('#usin').val();
                    var user = jQuery('#user').val();
                    var ph = jQuery('#ph').val();
                    var conductivity = jQuery('#conductivity').val();
                    var hardness = jQuery('#hardness').val();
                    var tds = jQuery('#tds').val();
                    var turbidity = jQuery('#turbidity').val();
                    var alkalinity = jQuery('#alkalinity').val();
                    var chloride = jQuery('#chloride').val();

                    jQuery.post("scripts/water_qual_add.php", {
                        "usin": usin,
                        "user": user,
                        "ph": ph,
                        "conductivity": conductivity,
                        "hardness": hardness,
                        "tds": tds,
                        "turbidity": turbidity,
                        "alkalinity": alkalinity,
                        "chloride": chloride
                    }, function (data) {

                        jQuery('#dialog-message').html(data);
                        jQuery('#dialog-message').dialog('open');
                        return false;

                        //jQuery('#usin').focus();
                    });
                }
            });

            jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                jQuery('.wql').keydown(function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 13) {
                        var index = jQuery('.wql').index(this) + 1;
                        jQuery('.wql').eq(index).focus();
                    }
                });

                jQuery("#dialog-message").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function () {
                            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                            jQuery('#eff_entry').each(function () {
                                this.reset();
                            });

                            jQuery('#usin').focus();
                        }
                    }
                });

                jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                    altField: "#stddate"
                });
                jQuery('#usin').focus();
                jQuery("#eff_entry").validate();
                jQuery("#usin").change(function () {
                    var usin = jQuery('[name="usin"]').val();
                    jQuery.post("get_sample_details.php", {
                        "usin": usin
                    }, function (data) {
                        if (data.msg) {
                            // message_box.show_message(data.msg,'Please Enter a valid no.');
                            alert(data.msg);
                            jQuery('#usin').focus();
                        } else {
                            jQuery('#submit_btn').show();
                            jQuery('#comment').hide();
                            jQuery('#doc').val(data.date);
                            jQuery('#desc').val(data.description);
                            jQuery('#loc').val(data.location);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });


            function RoundIt(Value)
            {
                return(Math.round(Value * 100)) / 100;
            }


        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .usin{
                background-color:#FFFF99;
                color:#FF0000;}

            #rawdate{position:absolute;
                     float:left;
                     width:500px;

            }
            #calculated{
                float:right;
                width:300px;
            }

            #eff_entry label.error, #eff_entry input.submit { margin-left: 110px; font-size:10px; color:#FF0000; }

            #comment{display:none;}
            .no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {  display: none;}

            div.ui-dialog{
                font-size:12px;

            }
        </style>
        <body onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    event.keyCode = 9;
                    return event.keyCode;
                }">
            <!-- DO NOT MOVE! The following AllWebMenus linking code section must always be placed right AFTER the BODY tag-->
            <!-- ******** BEGIN ALLWEBMENUS CODE FOR enviro_menu ******** -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var MenuLinkedBy = "AllWebMenus [4]", awmMenuName = "enviro_menu", awmBN = "766";
                awmAltUrl = "";
            </script>
            <script charset="UTF-8" src="enviro_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">awmBuildMenu();</script>
            <!-- ******** END ALLWEBMENUS CODE FOR enviro_menu ******** -->

            <div id="main">
                <div id="masthead">

                </div>
                <div id="dummy"></div>
                <!-- end masthead -->
                <div id="content">

                    <div id="welcome">Welcome&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['EMPNAME']; ?></div>

                    <hr class="noscreen" />
                    <form id="eff_entry" name="eff_entry" action="" >
                        <fieldset>
                            <div id="rawdata">
                                <legend>Water Quality Parameters</legend>
                                <label for="usin">USIN</label>
                                <input name="usin" id="usin" type="text" class="usin" onblur="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" required/>
                                <br />
                                <br/>

                                <label for="ph">pH</label>
                                <input class= "wql" name="ph" id="ph" value='0.0' required />
                                <label for="conductivity">Conductivity</label>
                                <input name="conductivity" id="conductivity" value='0.0'  required   />
                                <br />
                                <label for="tds">TDS</label>
                                <input class= "wql" name="tds" id="tds" value='0.0'  required/>
                                <br/>
                                <label for="turbidity">Turbidity</label>
                                <input class= "wql" name="turbidity" id="turbidity" value='0.0'  required />
                                <br/>
                                <label for="chloride">Chloride</label>
                                <input class= "wql" name="chloride" id="chloride" value='0.0' required />
                                <br/>
                                <label for="alkalinity">Alkalinity</label>
                                <input class= "wql" name="alkalinity" id="alkalinity" value='0.0' required />
                                <br />
                                <label for="hardness">Hardness</label>
                                <input class= "wql" name="hardness" id="hardness" value='0.0' required/>
                                <label for="user"> Data Entered By</label>
                                <input  id="user" name="user" style="color:#FF0000; background-color:#FFFF33; font-weight:bold" onfocus="this.blur();" onselectstart="event.returnValue=false;" value= "<?php echo $_SESSION['EMPNO']; ?>" />
                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                                <div align="center">
                                    <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="calculated">
                                <label for="loc">Location</label>
                                <input readonly="readonly" name="loc" id="loc"  /><br/>
                                <label for="desc">Type</label><br/>
                                <input readonly="readonly" name="desc" id="desc"  /><br/>
                                <label for="doc"> Date of Collection</label><br/>
                                <input readonly="readonly" name="doc" id="doc"  /><br/>

                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <div id="type2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--end content -->

            <!--end navbar -->
            <div id="siteInfo"><?php include('footer.php'); ?>  </div>
            <br />
            </div>
            <div id="dialog-message" class="dialog" title="Water Quality Data Entry"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

After searching similar question in stackoverflow, I found this which is doing half of the work.

```
jQuery('.wql').keypress(function(e){

        if ( e.which == 13 ) 
        e.preventDefault();


});
```

But this will prevent form from submitting, but it does not move focus to the next input. Is there any method?

Comment: Also never call anything in a form `name="submit"` it will break the submit handler if you need it

Comment: You also have an inline handler - that is not a great idea. (re)move it: `<body onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    event.keyCode = 9;
                    return event.keyCode;
                }">`

Comment: Check This Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009808/enter-key-press-behaves-like-a-tab-in-javascript

Comment: I removed it@mplungjan

Comment: @PrashantPatil I tried several options given in this, but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this, which is a rework of [Jquery focus on next element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338246/jquery-focus-on-next-element-with-class)

Please note that not all your input had the class that would allow the tabbing on enter, including the submit

```js
$(function () {
  var $fields = $('.wql');
  $fields.on("keypress",function (e) {
    console.log(e.which,$(this).next('.wql').attr("id"));
    if (e.which === 13 && this.id ="submit_btn") {
      e.preventDefault();
      var idx = $fields.index(this);
      $fields.eq(idx+1).focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">

  <div id="welcome">Welcome&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php echo $_SESSION[ 'EMPNAME']; ?>
  </div>

  <hr class="noscreen" />
  <form id="eff_entry" name="eff_entry" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <div id="rawdata">
        <legend>Water Quality Parameters</legend>
        <label for="usin">USIN</label>
        <input name="usin" id="usin" type="text" class="usin wql" onblur="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" required/>
        <br />
        <br/>

        <label for="ph">pH</label>
        <input class="wql" name="ph" id="ph" value='0.0' required />
        <label for="conductivity">Conductivity</label>
        <input class="wql" name="conductivity" id="conductivity" value='0.0' required />
        <br />
        <label for="tds">TDS</label>
        <input class="wql" name="tds" id="tds" value='0.0' required/>
        <br/>
        <label for="turbidity">Turbidity</label>
        <input class="wql" name="turbidity" id="turbidity" value='0.0' required />
        <br/>
        <label for="chloride">Chloride</label>
        <input class="wql" name="chloride" id="chloride" value='0.0' required />
        <br/>
        <label for="alkalinity">Alkalinity</label>
        <input class="wql" name="alkalinity" id="alkalinity" value='0.0' required />
        <br />
        <label for="hardness">Hardness</label>
        <input class="wql" name="hardness" id="hardness" value='0.0' required/>
        <label for="user">Data Entered By</label>
        <input class="wql" id="user" name="user" style="color:#FF0000; background-color:#FFFF33; font-weight:bold" onfocus="this.blur();" onselectstart="event.returnValue=false;" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['EMPNO']; ?>" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div align="center">
          <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="calculated">
        <label for="loc">Location</label>
        <input readonly="readonly" name="loc" id="loc" />
        <br/>
        <label for="desc">Type</label>
        <br/>
        <input readonly="readonly" name="desc" id="desc" />
        <br/>
        <label for="doc">Date of Collection</label>
        <br/>
        <input readonly="readonly" name="doc" id="doc" />
        <br/>

      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div id="type2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```